Payment Processor Error message :DB Error: No Such Field
CiviCRM was updated in the last few days, to 5.78.4, running on WordPress.
Since then (possibly unrelated but a bit much of a coincidence) no one has been able to make a contribution.
The card is authorised and appears to go through, but then
"Payment Processor Error message :DB Error: No Such Field"
Afterwards, the payments show as pending, but are not processed.
The donors probably don't even notice the error, but we have noticed that payments are not processing.
Is there a fix for this?

Yes, sounds likely to be related to the civicrm update. For a potential quick fix, visit extensions listing page /civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1 and see if there's a pending update to an extension. If that doesn't fix it, tell us more, e.g. which version of civicrm were you running before the update, and which payment processor is being used here. You'll also likely get some more clues if you look in your civicrm error log, which you can see using the "logviewer" extension. Specifically - it might help identify which table is missing which field.

Thanks, I'll take a look at that. It's Stripe, as it happens, and it was 5.65 something I think before, over a year out of date (that's another story).

It doesn't look as if any extensions have pending updates. All are on 5.78.4.

Ah, if your civicrm upgrade was BIG, then I'd put my money on a missing core field. Definitely check the logviewer or raw log files for the errors, they'll give you the information about which field is missing from which table. It might be a symptom of a bigger problem, of course.

Something I've found, which may or may not be relevant, is that there's an alert about a problem detected with the Stripe Webhook. Not sure how long it's been there.

Not relevant no.

I had the same issue with Stripe and fixed it by temporarily switching all payment methods on contribution/event pages from Stripe to Paypal. deleting the existing Stripe payment Processors, disabling and uninstalling the the Stripe extension. Then reinstalling Stripe from the extensions screen. Then setting it up again from scratch.
I've had Stripe installed for a long time and I think maybe updating over and over left some DB fields mismatched.
It didn't take too long and is working again now.
